# VML and opacity problem in raphael

Tags: internet-explorer, opacity, raphael, vml

I'm working on a raphael based script that can rotate, resize, flip and flop an image. I've faced strange problem in IE: when the image with opacity is rotated on some angle and then is applied by matrix to perform flip, there are black areas on it.

Image is rotated and flipped:
http://cl.ly/12067d913b6ef423ae59

See black borders?

I've already tried to apply AlphaImageLoader but nothing. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, so I would recommend filing a bug report with Raphael.

Comment: What's the original image look like? How about some code?

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot when a 24-bit PNG with alpha-channel transparency is run through IE's opacity filter (no version of IE before 9 has real support for the opacity CSS property).

If it's possible, the easiest fix would be to use a different image format with a fixed background color.